# Htaccess rules http to https redirecting too many times

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using simple htaccess rules to redirect http to https but it breaks the page and shows an error "Redirecting too many times" . Here is my code

**Approach -1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Approach -2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I tried both approaches but its not working. Here is the error i get:

[image]

Comment: Is the server running behind some kind of load balancer or reverse proxy?

Comment: This happened to me just last week - client was using Cloudflare and didn't tell me.  Check the response headers, make sure there's nothing there you don't expect.

Comment: Can you run this command `curl -IL 'http://example.com/'` from command line and paste the output here. (change `example.com` to your actual domain)

Answer (score 0):

You either have additional redirects that match similar conditions in your .htaccess or you are using a reverse proxy such as Cloudflare that also does https redirection.

Comment out your rewrite rules and sort them by the order that you want them to execute in the order of "general/generic" to "specific".  Un-comment them one at a time and test them.

Disable the https redirects built into your reverse proxy to test.

If you manage virtual hosts you may want to check at that level as well.